# Can a small monitor + powerful reading glasses be a substitute for a large monitor with same resolution?

Tags: eye, computers, glasses, eye-strain

Reading or focusing up close puts strain on the eyes and I believe can be bad in the long run. With that in mind, would keeping my monitor at a distance (3-4 feet) and using the right set of "magnifying" glasses for that distance be better? Are there any drawbacks of using such magnification for a person with otherwise normal eyesight?